# Как упаковать код Ruby в бинарник

Tags: ruby

Я только что написал свой первый "Привет мир" на Ruby. И у меня возник вопрос, ответ на который я не смог найти в Google.

Итак, вопрос: возможно ли "скомпилировать" код Ruby в бинарник (например в pyhton есть .py для исходных кодов в чистом виде и .pyc для бинарников)? И, если возможно, то как?

Comment: pyc - это не совсем бинарник, это просто байткод.

Но задам встречный вопрос - зачем Вам бинарник? Может воспользоваться нескриптовыми языками (С/С++, Pascal/Delphi, Go)?

Comment: Хочу написать мини-игру и не хочу чтобы можно было легко влезть в код и править переменные (мега крутая защита не нужна). А руби хвастается тем что на нем приложения пишутся очень быстро. Паскаль мне не нравится, го я не знаю а на си плюс плюс писать гораздо дольше, ктамуже не до конца понимаю тему с указатели и динамической памятью.

Comment: @Faydaen, а как насчет java?

Comment: А вот это Вы видели: [Is it possible to compile Ruby to byte code as with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972388/is-it-possible-to-compile-ruby-to-byte-code-as-with-python) ?

Comment: > Хочу написать мини-игру

напишите для начала.

> легко влезть в код и править переменные

кому нужно - поправит. Кому не нужно - никогда этого делать не будет. А постоянные апдейты сведут на нет "автокряки".

> руби хвастается тем что на нем приложения пишутся очень быстро

Мало чем он хвастается. Мой преподаватель по биологии говорил, что "если вы знаете ответ, то скорость его написания ограничивается только скоростью ручки - бумага может воспламениться"

> а как насчет java

тот же скриптовый язык, просто jit компиляцией:)

Comment: Путем небольшого поиска нашел упоминания rubyscript2exe, Exerb, Ocra и Ruby2exe, посмотрите их.

Comment: Спасибо, почитав ссылку я пришел к выводу что ответ на мой вопрос таков: Нет, разработчики руби не предназначили его для упаковки в бинарник. Но тем не мение есть некоторые способы его упаковать.

Answer (score 3):

Нътъ.

Если пользоваться Rubinus (реализация Ruby), то можно получить аналогичные питоновским *.rbc . Но как уже было сказано в комментариях, это не бинарник, а байткод. А как и всякий байткод его можно декомпилировать.

Зачем вам скрывать свой код? В этом нет никакого смысла.

PS: Ruby неподходящий язык для написания игр.

**UPD**:

> руби хвастается тем что на нем приложения пишутся очень быстро.

Справедливо только для веб-приложений. С графикой всё совсем по-другому. Даже на Python писать игры лучше чем на Ruby.

> ктамуже не до конца понимаю тему с указатели и динамической памятью.

В такой случае писать игру рано. Поиграйся с Unreal Engine, Blender Game Engine.