# Можно ли конвертировать .rb в .exe

Tags: ruby, конвертация

Недавно я начал изучать язык Ruby и сделал на нём игру и задался вопросом можно ли конвертировать файл Ruby в exe, если можно то как это сделать?

Comment: https://github.com/larsch/ocra#building-an-executable

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как упаковать код Ruby в бинарник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/332092/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-ruby-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba)